# Python: WebSocket Connection Unable to Recognize Coroutine

Tags: python, websocket

So I'm learning how to use websockets on Python and I copied the instructor's code.  But it worked for him and I got an error.  For some reason, the client object is recognized, then unrecognized later.

Here's the code:

```
import websockets
import asyncio
import pyodbc

class WebSocketClient():

    def __init__(self):
        self.cnxn = None
        self.crsr = None

    def database_connect(self):

        # Define server and database
        server = 'DESKTOP-O9QIKO1\SQLEXPRESS'
        database = 'Database'
        sql_driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

        # Define database connection
        self.cnxn = pyodbc.connect(driver = sql_driver,
                                   server = server,
                                   database = database,
                                   trusted_connection = 'yes')

        self.crsr = self.cnxn.cursor()

    def database_insert(self, query, data_tuple):

        self.crsr.execute(query, data_tuple)
        self.cnxn.commit()
        self.cnxn.close()
        print('Data has been successfully inserted into the database')

    async def connect(self):

        uri = "wss://" + userPrincipalsResponse['streamerInfo']['streamerSocketUrl'] + "/ws"

        self.connection = await websockets.client.connect(uri)

        if self.connection.open:
            print("Connection established. Client correctly connected.")
            return self.connection

    async def sendMessage(self, message):
        await self.connection.send(message)

    async def receiveMessage(self, connection):

        while True:

            try:

                # Decode message
                message = await connection.recv()
                message_decoded = json.loads(message)

                # Prepare data for insertion, connect to database
                query = "INSERT INTO  td_service_data (service, timestamp, command) VALUES (?,?,?);"
                self.database_connect()

                if 'data' in message_decoded.keys():

                    # Grab data
                    data = message_decoded['data'][0]
                    data_tuple = (data['service'], data['timestamp'], data['command'])

                    # Insert data
                    self.database_insert(query, data_tuple)

                print('-'*20)
                print('Received message from server ' + str(message))

            except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
                print('Connection with server closed')
                break

    async def heartbeat(self, connection):

        while True:
            try:
                await connection.send('ping')
                await aysncio.sleep(5)

            except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
                print('Connection with server closed')
                break



import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Create client object
    client = WebSocketClient()

    # Define event loop
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    # Start a connection to the websocket
    connection = loop.run_until_complete(client.connect())

    # Define tasks to run
    tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(client.receiveMessage(connection)),
             asyncio.ensure_future(client.sendMessage(login_encoded)),
             asyncio.ensure_future(client.receiveMessage(connection)),
             asyncio.ensure_future(client.sendMessage(data_encoded)),
             asyncio.ensure_future(client.receiveMessage(connection))]

    # Run tasks
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
```

When I run this, I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-1d8d99c4eed9> in <module>
     11 
     12     # Start a connection to the websocket
---> 13     connection = loop.run_until_complete(client.connect())
     14 
     15     # Define tasks to run

AttributeError: module 'websockets' has no attribute 'client'
```

But when I ran `client`, I got `<__main__.WebSocketClient at 0x232d7ce7048>`. 
 And when I ran `client.connect()`, I got `<coroutine object WebSocketClient.connect at 0x00000232D7DE3948>`, so it does recognize `client`, doesn't it?

I'm so confused.  Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Based on the error it looks like you probably named your program websockets.py--- that's going to mess with your import of the websockets library module.  If that's what you did, rename your program to something other than websockets.py and give it another try.

Comment: What if I uninstall it then reinstall it?

Comment: I doubt if there's anything wrong with your websockets module, so there's probably little point in uninstalling and reinstalling it (if that's what you're talking about).  If you named the program that you've written websockets.py, you'd get the error that you're getting, I don't know if you've done that (as you haven't told us the name of your program) and there may be another cause for that error.  But the most likely cause of what you're experiencing is that you named your script websockets.py.  If your script is called websockets.py rename it.

Comment: Well, I downloaded it directly from https://pypi.org/project/websockets, so it was already called "websockets".  What might have happened was when I couldn't see what the extension of the file was, I put .py to the end of it.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, after I did `pip install websockets`, Python gave me an error, saying `No module named 'websockets'`. I guess my solution to get rid of that error was the wrong solution.  Now, for some reason, when I tried to uninstall it, the system said websockets did not exist.  So I reinstalled it but got the no module error back.

Comment: Finally fixed!  Thank you.  I did have to add a sys.path.append.